# Chaining dynamic laravel database query builder methods

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am attempting to chain multiple query builder methods. Everything goes fine but when I use the get() method to return a response, the response comes with no body. 
Request - GET /accounts?sort=name desc,created_at desc
Here is my controller:

```
use SortedCollection;

protected $sortableAttributes = ["name", "created_at"];

public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->sort != null) :
        $validSortPairs = $this->validateSortQueryParam($this->sortableAttributes, $request->sort);

        $queryBuilder = Account::query();
        $databaseSortQuery = $this->getDatabaseSortQuery($validSortPairs, $queryBuilder);

        return $databaseSortQuery->get();
    endif;
}
```

And here is my SortedCollection trait:

```
public function getDatabaseSortQuery($validatedSortPairs, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder)
{
    foreach ($validatedSortPairs as $key => $sortPair) {
        $queryBuilder->orderBy($sortPair["sortAttribute"], $sortPair["sortOrder"]);
    }

    return $queryBuilder;
}
```

Comment: What do you get with `dd($databaseSortQuery->get())`?

Comment: I get a collection
`Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: array:50 [▶]
}`

Comment: Well that means your query builder is likely working correctly. If you are trying to return a view with the `__invoke` function, you'll need to explicitly call `return view('your.view.blade', $dataArray)`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views for moe info